# Pivot reshape dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need help reshaping a DataFrame that i got from a csv file.

In this file I have the first column as ID and then 97 columns that represent sale units of 4 products during time.

the data is like

```
id    p1_201501   p1_201502 ......  p1_201812  p2_201501..... p2_2018012   p3_.. 

x12     125         12        ......  06          500     ..... 14         2...              
nz15     250         16        ......  600         423     ..... 312        56...     
....
```

The Id represent the area in which the product is sold. And I have 700 rows (i.e 700 df['id'].nunique() ) And so I need to find the yearly sales trend of a given product. So i thought the solution is to change the dataframe in order to have years as rows and the quantity for each product (p1, p2, p3)

Something like:

```
id    date        p1   p2    p3
x12   201501     12   500   32 
      201502    .... 
      201503    ....
      ....
      201812    .....
nz15  201501    .....
      201502    .....
      .....
      201812    .....
```

But I don't know if it is the right choice to find the saled trend in this case and if so How to change the first dataframe to be like the second I know some about pivot reshape. But I can't find how to do it and how to keep the id (the area in which the product is sold)

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my intial dataframe :

```
     id  p1_201501  p1_201502  p1_201803  p2_201801  p2_201812
0   x12        125         12          6        500         14
1  nz15        250         16        600        423         32
2  qz15        350          4         20        223         32
```

my program:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["id"], var_name="product", value_name="values").reset_index(drop=True)
df['date'] = df['product'].str.split('_',n = 1, expand=True)[1]
df['year'] = df['date'].astype(str).str[:-2]
df['month'] = df['date'].astype(str).str[4:]

#drop unused columns
df.drop(['product','date'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df = df[['id', 'year','month','values']]
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'year','month'], ascending=[True,True,True]).reset_index(drop=True)
df.set_index(['id','year','month'])

#just sum each annual total sales for each id
df = df.groupby(['id','year'])['values'].sum()

print(df)
```

final result:

```
id    year
nz15  2015     266
      2018    1055
qz15  2015     354
      2018     275
x12   2015     137
      2018     520
```

Comment: if its okay dont forget to validate please

Comment: If you are talking about the vote. I can't because i don't have the rights to do it. I get 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: no i speak about validate the answer